# How can I deploy my app to a container OS without using Docker Hub?

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, amazon-ecs, coreos, rancher

I want to deploy my app to DigitalOcean using Docker and a container OS like CoreOS or, preferably, RancherOS.  I'm familiar enough with Docker that I can build images.  However, most of the documentation from both projects talks about deploying containers using Docker Hub.  I don't want to use Docker Hub, AWS ECS, etc.

The only other way I can think of to deploy my app, then, would be to use `docker export` and SSH/SFTP to get my app onto my DigitalOcean droplet.  Is this the preferred way of deploying Docker images that aren't on Docker Hub or similar services?

On a side note, I have looked at Rancher (the app).  I'm not looking for anything as complex as Kubernetes, Swarm, Rancher, etc.  I'm not concerned with scaling at the moment.  I'm mostly just interested in using Docker as a convenient way to package my app with its minimum dependencies and using a container OS to avoid worrying about locking down the massive attack surface of a full-blown Linux distro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should follow these steps to export the image if you don't want to use a registry:

`docker save <image name> > <image name>.tar`

`scp <image name>.tar <server-address>`

Then on your server do,

`docker load < <image name>.tar`

That will load your image in the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try any Docker Registry which is available on publically.

- docker-hub [**is one of them**]
- gitlab.com also provides docker-registry
- artifactory (jFrog)
- nexus

These are few Docker Registry provider - if you can install them and make them accessible through internet - then you can easily use them in any public cloud provider (e.g. Digital Ocean)

You can also use AWS to install and run NEXUS in free tier machines which will give you , your own nexus instance.

Another way - **like you said** is

- to export Docker Image (tar format) from current system and
- transfer to the target environment , and
- then import into local docker images.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid any public registries.

Comment: OK, In that case: you can also use AWS to install and run NEXUS in free tier machines which will give you , your own private nexus instance.